# calculating vmaf using ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, vmaf

I am trying to calculate `VMAF` using FFmpeg. for this, I installed `ffmepg-python` and used the following code in python.

```
from ffmpeg_quality_metrics import FfmpegQualityMetrics as ffqm
a=ffqm("E:/6.mp4","E:/6_fast.mp4").calc(["vmaf"])
```

it produced a `dic` and contains `PSNR`, `SSIM`, and some other things besides `VMAF` for each frame. but I just need to have VMAF. I have a folder of `mp4` files and I need to calculate `VMAF` for each of these videos( and their reference videos) and then save a text file for each of them that contains `VMAF` value for each frame. before, I used the following python code for calculating PSNR and I need something like this for `VMAF`, but I could not find anything. could you please help me with this issue? Thanks

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg.exe', '-i', pname1, '-i', pname2, '-lavfi', f'psnr=stats_file={n}', '-f', 'null', '-'])
```

how can I save these `VMAF` values in a dic into a text file? It also time consuming. is it reasonalbe?

Comment: "It also time consuming. is it reasonalbe?" Yes, VMAF is several times slower than PSNR/SSIM.